# How to show dst free timezone offset?

Tags: php, datetime, dst, timezone-offset

have a timezone info field that shows the timezone offset ( e.g 'UTC+1' ). used 'getOffset' for this, but now in dst time, its returning 'UTC+2' for the same timezone.

my question is how to detect if dst is enabled or how to get the dst free offset ?

checked DateTimeZone and DateTime docu but haven't found anything.

Comment: Sounds a bit like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Yes, timezones change their UTC offsets throughout the year. That's why just storing the UTC offset is pretty useless, if you want to refer to the same *timezone* later. You should be storing the *timezone* like `Europe/Amsterdam`, then you can figure out its UTC offset as needed. Just having "UTC+2" doesn't even tell you whether the country observes DST or not and in which direction "DST-free" would be at any given time.

Comment: Read up on [localtime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.localtime.php), specifically the *$is_associative* parameter.  And, what @deceze said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only get the information whether something is currently in DST or not from a `Date` object; a `DateTimeZone` never "is" in DST or not, it merely contains the information *when* a date goes into DST, so it always depends on a particular `Date` instance. There's no dedicated method for that on the `Date` class, but it's a possible [date formatter](https://php.net/date):

```
echo 'Is DST: ', $date->format('I') ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

Comment: perfect :) thats what i was looking for